# Converting google::protobuf::RepeatedField<float> to float

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am using Google's Protobuf to create a C++ class called `Foo`, as follows:

```
message Foo
{
    optional int32 x = 1;
    repeated float y = 2;
}
```

In the created C++ class, this creates a member variable `y` of type `const google::protobuf::RepeatedField<float>`. Now, in my C++ code, I want to access the `x` and `y` variables of an instance of `Foo`, called `foo`. In this example, `y` is of length one, i.e. it contains one float:

```
int a = foo.x();
float b = foo.y();
float c = foo.y()[0];
```

Here, the first line works, but I get errors for both the second and third lines. I am just trying to get the value of this float that is stored in `y`.

How should I be doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
float b = foo.y(0);
```

(Stack overflow is complaining that my answer is to short...)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your Y-s

```
for(auto value : Foo.y())
{
    //do something with value here
}
```